# Laravel 5 Validate Birthdate From Select Fields

Tags: laravel, select

I have a registration form with 3 select fields (month, day, year) which I want to grab, convert to proper date format, and validate. So, below are the 3 select boxes.

```
<div class="birthday_selects">
    <select name="birthday_month">
    ....
    </select>
    <select name="birthday_day">
    ....
    </select>
    <select name="birthday_year">
    ....
    </select>
</div>
```

I've read that I can use the following, but I get the error "...Http\Input not found..."

```
$birthday = Input::get('birthday_month')."-".Input::get('birthday_day')."-".Input::get('birthday_year')'
```

Okay, I can dd($birthday) and it comes out in the m-d-y as I've concatenated there. Now, I'm trying to validate that date against a prior date (to see if user is >13 years old). I'm using the following, but no luck.

```
    public function postSignup(Request $request)
{

    $birthdate = Input::get('birthday-month')."-".Input::get('birthday-day')."-".Input::get('birthday-year');

    $this->validate($request, [
        $birthdate => 'required',
    ]);

    dd($birthdate);
}
```

When just having it be required, it doesn't work.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're doing it wrong. What is wrong with it is the rule.

The **rule key** must be present in the form field's name. 
For your answer, let's assume the $birthday will be 'jul-15-1992'. and you're going to put that variable inside the rule as a key. So, that's not valid because the field will never be present in the form field.

```
public function formPost(Request $request)
{
    $rule = [ 
        'birth_year'  => 'required|numeric',
        'birth_day'   => 'required|numeric',
        'birth_month' => 'required|numeric', // may be a string
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rule);
    // check if the day is valid for the month manually.
    // then form the DOB now.        
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Aside from the proper syntax, I'm trying to figure how to work it out logically. Using the rules you have there, we require each select menu to have something in there and for it to be a numeric value, but then the question is figuring out how to combine the 3 select boxes (which I provided earlier) and comparing that date to today to see if it's greater than 13.

Comment: your previous code is correct to do what you're doing. What you're asking is like spoon feeding. I can't do that. sorry. But I can give you resources. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php 2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php 
Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Carbon date  and add new [birth_day] input:

```
$all = $request->all();
$year = $all['birthday_year'];
$month = $all['birthday_month'];
$day = $all['birthday_day'];

 // Create Carbon date
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);

//add new [birth_day] input
$request->request->add(['birth_day' => $date->format('Y-m-d')]); 

$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'birth_day' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|before:today',// validate birth day
]);
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: If either of the year, month or day is empty the createFromFormat fails. How can this be handled?

Comment: you can validate before submit data:
ex: 
```<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="birthday_month" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  ...
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>```